# Accessing Node Modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, yeoman, node-modules

I have an app that I scaffolded out using Yeoman (yeoman.io w/ generator-webapp). I need to use the mailchimp api so I installed the official api client (npm install mailchimp-api). The mailchimp-api folder is now in the node_modules directory of my app. My problem is that I have no idea how to interact with it from my generator-webapp application. Do I need to import the module some how into my main.js file in order to access its functionality? If so how?

Im new to Node but I have a lot of experience with JS, so I apologize if this question seems super obvious or basic.

**Update:**
I added these lines to my grunt.js file:

```
var mcapi = require('mailchimp-api');
var mc = new mcapi.Mailchimp('xxx');
```

However, I am still unclear on how to interact with `mc` from the client side.

Comment: `var mcapi = require('mailchimp-api')`. They provide [an example application](https://github.com/mailchimp/mcapi2-node-examples) on their Github.

Comment: @MikeC Yep, I've tried that in my main.js file however, I get the following error: require is not defined

Comment: How are you executing the file?

Comment: Are you running it through Node.js? That code isn't supposed to run in a browser.

Comment: @FelixKling Grunt serve

Comment: @MikeC Im trying to figure out how to take data from the browser and send it back to the mailchimp api module from the application I scaffolded out with yeoman.

Comment: That requires some kind of AJAX request or a socket connection. I highly suggest you look through the example project they provide to get an idea of how to use this module.

Comment: @MikeC I ran through the example project and successfully made the api calls I needed to make. The problem is that I can't access the mailchimp node module from the app I scaffolded. I understand how the module works and how to interact with it. I do not understand how to access it from within the context of this new app.

Comment: The problem has to be that you're attempting to access the API in client-side code. `require` is built into Node.js so as long as you're running that code server-side then you will be able to access the module.

Comment: Where in the context of my application, should I attempt to use require()?

Comment: @MikeC I added the require to my grunt.js file, however I am still unclear on how to interact with the module from the client side. I need to submit email address data to the api.

Comment: You need to setup a route which captures the user input and work with it from there. [Read through the example project](https://github.com/mailchimp/mcapi2-node-examples/blob/master/express/routes/lists.js#L15) and become familiar with AJAX.